# beautiful soup - getting a text from a tag inside another tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

i am trying to parse a web page using beautiful soup [for the first time in my life] and i am experiencing a strange error. there is a tag within a tag in html structure, and i keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

the structure of html tag is following:
the whole grid of items on the page is within div class "properties_reviews" which then goes into div class "preview" for a particular item and that class "preview" has two more classes: "preview-media" for photo and "preview-content" for text info i need to parse. the class "preview-content" has `[a]` tag that contains two `[span]` tags with price and square of the item, and a `[h2]` tag with a territory i also need.

```
<div class="properties-previews">
    <div class="preview"
        <div class="preview-media">
        <div class="preview-content">
            <a href="/properties/1042-us-highway-1-hancock-me-04634/1330428"
               class="preview__link">
                <span class="preview__price">$89,900</span>
                <span class="preview__size">1 ac</span>
                <div class="preview__subtitle">
                    <h2 class="-g-truncated preview__subterritory">Hancock County
                    </h2>
                    <span class="preview__extended">-- sq ft</span>
                </div>
            </a>
```

so i am trying to get out **$89,990** from `preview_price`; **1 ac** from `preview_size`; **hancock county** from `preview_subtitle` and my python code so far has been something like this (i have omitted all imports and requests):

```
landplots = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'properties-previews')

for l in landplots:
  plot_price = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview_price'})
  plot_square = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview_size'})
  plot_county = l.find('h2', class_ = '-g-truncated preview__subterritory').text
  plot_location = l.find('span', class_ = 'preview__locality -g-truncated').text

  print(plot_price).text
  print(plot_county)
```

what am i doing wrong? i've come to understanding that once a tag is within another tag there should be some special syntax to get those words, but the error saying i have no text at all (on both prints i am doing) confuses me a lot. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each value is under a text node. So you can invoke `.find_next(text=True)` to extract the desired data items

```
html='''
<div class="properties-previews">
 <div <div="" class="preview-media">
  <div class="preview-content">
   <a class="preview__link" href="/properties/1042-us-highway-1-hancock-me-04634/1330428">    
    <span class="preview__price">
     $89,900
    </span>
    <span class="preview__size">
     1 ac
    </span>
    <div class="preview__subtitle">
     <h2 class="-g-truncated preview__subterritory">
      Hancock County
     </h2>
     <span class="preview__extended">
      -- sq ft
     </span>
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

landplots = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'preview-content')#.find_all('div',class_="preview-media")

for l in landplots:
  plot_price = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview__price'}).find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)
  plot_square = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview__size'}).find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)
  plot_county = l.find('h2', class_ = '-g-truncated preview__subterritory').find_next(text=True).text
 
  print(plot_price)
  print( plot_square)
```

**Output:**

```
$89,900
1 ac
```

Update: It's working fine without any issues according html dom

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url='https://www.landsearch.com/industrial/united-states/p1'
res= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

landplots = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'preview-content')#.find_all('div',class_="preview-media")

for l in landplots:
  plot_price = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview__price'}).find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)
  plot_square = l.find('span', {"class": 'preview__size'}).find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)
  plot_county = l.find('h2', class_ = '-g-truncated preview__subterritory').find_next(text=True).text
 
  print(plot_price)
  print( plot_square)
```

**Output:**

```
$89,900
1 ac    
$995,000
2.32 ac 
$85,000 
0.93 ac 
$888,000
11 ac   
$599,000
21.6 ac 
$225,000
3.72 ac 
$100,000
6.5 ac  
$75,000
4.48 ac
$749,000
8.2 ac
$225,000
84.5 ac
$225,000
84.5 ac
$275,000
29 ac
$275,000
29 ac
$40,000
0.22 ac
$2,330,000
2.8 ac
$535,000
3.71 ac
$169,900
34 ac
$499,000
1 ac
$299,000
2.53 ac
$299,000
2.53 ac
$299,000
2.53 ac
$799,000
2 ac
$199,000
0.79 ac
$997,600
3.27 ac
$699,000
1.71 ac
$529,000
1 ac
$499,900
1 ac
$50,000
1.14 ac
$250,000
55 ac
$50,000
1.14 ac
$11,000,000
31.4 ac
$1,200,000
1.68 ac
$94,900
85 ac
$896,000
2.38 ac
$189,000
1 ac
```

Comment: that helped, thanks! do you have any ideas why the parser gives me only 6 first results and then stops? there are as much as 35  items on the page, we should have captured all of them with the for loop, right?

Comment: As you didn't share the url , so it's a bit tough to make sure but You have to select each listing correctly then to iterate if they  are static html dom elements –

Comment: url is: https://www.landsearch.com/industrial/united-states/p1. i thought that exactly what i was doing, but somehow does not work

Comment: you have a url without "/p1" at the end of it. maybe that is the problem? however, i will need that p1 when i'll do parsing, because i want to iterate over other pages as well to get more data.

Comment: This is the 1st page then p2 is the 2nd page and when you will make the pagination it will work to its pagination rule

Comment: See the update. p1 output is same  meaning that url and p1 are the same

Comment: yes, now i got the idea and successfully managed to parse 100 pages i need. thank you so much for your help!